# How can I identify the message type received?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am using mule 3.5.

I have 2 flows to send a message, but I have to know what is the message type, if it is a JSON, an Object or a XML, so how can I do that? I read something about filters,  but I dont know how to use, cause did not find any example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation?

[Using Filters](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Filters)

The first example shows filtering based on the type of the payload.

You can also check the type using expressions, see [Mule Expression Language](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL)